# Index of maximum unicode codepoint

Tags: python, unicode

```
>>> i = 0
... while True:
...     try:
...         chr(i)
...     except ValueError:
...         print(i)
...         break
...     i += 1
...         
1114112
```

Is this number in the stdlib somewhere?  At the moment I'm parsing it from `chr.__doc__` (`unichr.__doc__` on Python 2) which seems lame.

The valid range for the argument depends how Python was configured – it may be either UCS2 [0..0xFFFF] or UCS4 [0..0x10FFFF].  I'm not sure if other ranges are possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [`sys.maxunicode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxunicode):

> An integer giving the value of the largest Unicode code point, i.e. `1114111` (`0x10FFFF` in hexadecimal).
>
> *Changed in version 3.3:* Before PEP 393, `sys.maxunicode` used to be either `0xFFFF` or `0x10FFFF`, depending on the configuration option that specified whether Unicode characters were stored as UCS-2 or UCS-4.